# c++ Armadillo matrix circular buffer and row assignment

Tags: multithreading, c++11, matrix, armadillo

I'm trying to populate an arma::mat data_mat(n,n) from a streaming data of size n in each time step. Its a high frequency real time system. So, efficiency and thread safety are very important design goals. With this in mind, 
1) What is the best (efficient,threadsafe) way to populate the data_mat with a vector (double/float) in each time step until it is finished populating n rows.
2)After n rows are populated,the rows should be circularly buffered with row elements being shifted upward or downward.

I tried data_mat.row(i)=vec
however,I'm not sure if its the most efficient way.
And I'm emulating circular buffer by copying in a loop but I guess its not very efficient. Any advice would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Note: For circular buffer workaround, I'm aware of data_mat= arma::shift(data_mat,shift_rows); however, I'm afraid, since its an assignment. For large matrices it can be an efficiency bottleneck. I'm serarching for inline/inplace functions/operations